# Parse nvarchar value that looks like a simplified XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a column of type `nvarchar(1000)` that contains something that looks like an `XML`:

```
<Master>  
   <NodeA>lorem ipsum</NodeA>  
   <NodeB>lorem ipsum</NodeB>  
   <NodeC>lorem ipsum</NodeC>  
   <NodeD>lorem ipsum</NodeD>  
</Master>
```

The value `might` have some carriage return and new lines embedded on it.

What would be the easiest way to get the value inside `NodeA`?

I've tried to remove the hardcoded string value `<masterA>` but then I feel I'm doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @XmlTable TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL, XmlContent NVARCHAR(1000))

INSERT INTO @XmlTable (ID, XmlContent)
VALUES (1, N'<Master>  
   <NodeA>lorem ipsum</NodeA>  
   <NodeB>lorem ipsum</NodeB>  
   <NodeC>lorem ipsum</NodeC>  
   <NodeD>lorem ipsum</NodeD>  
</Master>')

SELECT
    CAST(XmlContent AS XML).value('(/Master/NodeA)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM
    @XmlTable
WHERE
    ID = 1
```

But if your column really only stores XML - you should make it an `XML` column - that's easier (no need to always do a `CAST(... AS XML)` before applying any XQuery methods), and it's also optimized in terms of storage.

Comment: ...changing the DB field to XML would mean I would just remove the CASTING on the SELECT statement, is that right?

Comment: @SDDeveloper: yes, and it would enable  certain operations that **won't work** with a `CAST`..... (like using the `.nodes()` function in a `CROSS APPLY` situation)